# How to add syntax highlighting for .nbs files in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I cant't seem to find any plugin that does this.

Does anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean by ".nbs files"? Give some more information.

Comment: nbs (NetBeans Scripts/Schliemann) files are used to define languages on NetBeans Platform

Comment: I think that this approach for adding new languages is now discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

It is already there, I use NetBeans 8.2 and when you open a NBS file it will highlights the code inside. It is not perfect, because you have to click a bit inside the file and maybe close and open it again but it is still there. You can create a ticket for improvements here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS